# Why Naming Convention for pages in Asp.net are opposite to The Global Conventions?

Tags: asp.net, naming-conventions

In asp.net when we use code behind pages somename.aspx page inherit somename.aspx.cs
Means code behind page is parent but the name for the page is taken as if .aspx is being inherited by .cs

Comment: @ Caspar Kleijne: Actually My question is like we have parent name as 2 the its child will be 2.1, 2.2 similarly further child names will be 2.1.1 so on; means child has its parent the name added in it but  in case of aspx page name .cs page do have its child name page added in it.

Answer (score 2):

The file type for the code behind is different to the page though -- one is a cs file (i.e. c# source code) and the other an aspx file (i.e. ASP.Net page). Given the file type is determined by the operating system to be the last segment, it has to be named in this way.

Comment: Actually i'm not asking about extension. My question is like we have parent name as 2 the its child will be 2.1, 2.2 similarly further child names will be 2.1.1 so on; means child has its parent the name added in it but  in case of aspx page name .cs page do have its child name page added in it

Comment: @jagdeep I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to say? If you're saying the .aspx file is the child of the .aspx.cs file, then I'd disagree, given you *can* have an .aspx file without a code behind file, making it the "parent" of the code behind, in the same way that .designer.cs file is the child of the .cs file (in winforms)

Comment: But simply when we use code behind file with designer in the .aspx page it is shown if this page inherit from the file(Example:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChkBxList_2.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChkBxList_2" %>) with .cs extension in that case still the naming are that .cs page contain child name in it.